# Bootstrap - part of dropdown list items not appearing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a table where at the end of every row, I have a dropdown menu. The dropdown has 6 list items where 2 of the list items are showing but the remaining 4 items seems to be hiding. It appears to be entering the back of the next row.

```
<div class="dropdown pull-right"> 
 <a class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                Dropdown 
</a> 
<ul class="dropdown-menu from-right"> 
        <li><a class="dropdown-item">Dropdown menu item 1</a></li>  
        <li><a class="dropdown-item">Dropdown menu item 2</a></li> 
        <li><a class="dropdown-item">Dropdown menu item 3</a></li>  
        <li><a class="dropdown-item">Dropdown menu item 4</a></li> 
        <li><a class="dropdown-item">Dropdown menu item 5</a></li>  
        <li><a class="dropdown-item">Dropdown menu item 6</a></li> 
     </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add the html for the table as well. Dropdowns work fine in this fiddle http://www.bootply.com/UfGMoXwMy3

Comment: I have done that but still not working. I see the full dropdown list when i scroll down but I don't when I don't scroll

Comment: No you  haven't because I don't see any table html in your snippet.